# Only show webpage to mobile browsers

Tags: html

I've got a html5 website/webapp. I only want people to view this website/webapp from their mobile phone i.e. iphone, android, blackberry.

If they try to visit the website/webapp from their desktop browser, It should display an error message as the website/webapp is only meant for the mobile phone.

Is this possbile? any tips?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to check for sure wether a site is on mobile or desktop. HTML is made to be device agnostic.

you can do browsersniffing BUT

1. user_agents are easily changed in several browsers
2. you need to make sure to keep your user agent->mobile/desktop mapping up to date

you could do mediaqueries and conditionally display a query that way, but with the large array of formfactors available today there's no clear line to draw that way either.

Both methods will be prone to misidentification.

Quite Frankly, I'm kinda puzzled why you would want to prevent people from accessing your site. Why do you care if someone accesses your site from a desktop instead of a mobile device?

A site designed for mobile will work on a desktop just fine (it's the other way around that might be problematic)

Answer (score 0):

Grab the script for the language you prefer from here:

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use media queries, on the page and check the device width on which the page is width. Say if the page is viewed on Desktop, You can show a Message that this App is compatible with Mobiles Devices only and Not Desktops. similarly this should apply for tablets as well and this message can be customized.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any serer side technologies (ASP.NET, PHP) to generate the page? If so, you can perform your logic on the server side and return different content (like your message) on the desktop requests.

This is usually done by reading the user-agent. Are you ok with a desktop user over-riding their user agent to simulate a mobile browser and viewing the mobile content?